# ¿Cómo se consolidan todos los proyectos en una sola carpeta?

Tags: git, github, control-de-versiones

Al intentar agregar mi solución a control de código fuente de Vusual Studio 2017 Community me sale este mensaje:

> La solucion actual tiene proyectos ubicados fuera de la carpeta de soluciones. Estos proyectos no se controlaran por codigo fuente en el repositorio GIT. Para agregar todos los proyectos a un unico repositorio GIT, consolide todos los proyectos en una sola carpeta.

¿Cómo hago para consolidar todos los proyectos en una sola carpeta?

---

Estoy usando Visual studio 2017 community

Comment: ¿Dónde te sale este error? ¿Al hacer `git push`? Probablemente la solución sea tan simple como mover todos los ficheros _dentro_ del repositorio, si es que (como parece) alguno se puso fuera por error.

Comment: al ir a Archivo>Agregar al control de codigo fuente. he podido crear un repositorio pero no estan todos los archivos de la solucion dentro de el y el aviso sigue saliendo cuando voy a Archivo>Agregar al control de codigo fuente

Comment: Entiendo que estás trabajando con algún IDE. ¿Podrías especificar cuál para que podamos ayudarte mejor? Sugiero también mirar los logs de esa aplicación.